# Closed form solution of PDE of Option Price

Tags: options, stochastic-calculus, finance, black-scholes-pde

Let $V=V(S_t,t)$ be the option price and 
\begin{align}
V_t+\mu\,S\,V_S+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\,S^2\,V_{SS}=0\\
V(S_T,T)=\ln (S_T)^{2}.
\end{align}
**My question**: How can I obtain a closed form solution of $V=V(S_t,t)$. Please help me.

Comment: @Richard,Hi Richard I am New member.Is my question  wrong?

Comment: @Richard ,Please guide me

Comment: Everything fine .. I just thought that the correct expression is "closed form solution". So I edited the question. I hope this is fine with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Feynman–Kac Theorem**: Assume that $F$ is a solution to the boundary value problem
\begin{align}
&F_t+\mu(t,x)F_x+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,x)F_{xx}-rF=0\\
&F(T,x)=\Phi(x),
\end{align}
Assume furthermore that the process $e^{-r_s}\sigma(s,X_s)F_s$ is in $\mathcal L^2$ where 
\begin{align}
dX_s=\mu(s,x)ds+\sigma(s,x)dW_s,
\end{align}
then $F$ has the representation.
\begin{align}
F(t,x)=e^{-r(T-t)}E^Q_{t,x}[\Phi(X_T)]
\end{align}
Now, let 
\begin{align}
dS_t=\mu S_tdt+\sigma S_tdW_t
\end{align}
by application Ito lemma,we have
\begin{align} 
\ln S_T=\ln S_t\,\,+(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)+\sigma\,(W_T-W_t) 
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
&V(S_t,t)=e^{-0\times(T-t)}E^Q_{t,s}[\ln(S_T)^2]=E^Q_{t,s}[2\ln(S_T)]\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=E^Q_{t,s}[2\ln(S_t)+2(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)+2\sigma\,(W_T-W_t)]\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=2\ln(S_t)+2(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)+2\sigma\,E^Q_{t,s}[(W_T-W_t)]\\
\end{align}
The process $W_t$ has independent increments,therefor
\begin{align}
V(S_t,t)=2\ln(S_t)+2(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)
\end{align}

Comment: It would be nice to have a solution without using any SDE for $S$, that is, only use the PDE and the boundary condition.

Comment: Wasn't the payoff $\ln^2(S_T)$?